# React: trying to use jquery after componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a react Class component using the `componentDidMount` method. I'm trying to append things to a div after the entire component is rendered.

For each react component rendered it includes a `div` with a unique `id` such as `chartcarsousel1` or `chartcarousel2` or `charttopmovies`. The unique `id` in each rendered component comes from adding the string `'chart'` with a variable passed to the component. For example if the variable name is key, the div's `id` will be: 'chart'+key.

I'm trying to append some things to that div in my react component after it is rendered but this does not work:

```
 componentDidMount(){
   $('div#chart'+key).html("test");
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be done with jQuery rather than letting React handle the rendering of a new element?

Comment: Yes, directly modifying the DOM is anathema to SPA apps.

Comment: I think this is really charming, now go on and take a small React controlled components youtube video for dinner and leave jQuery behind. It is completely pointless nowadays as it filled a gap for cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing jQuery with React could be a really bad idea if you don't understand React properly. Use some references and arrays to render a list of children. I suggest to take an only React's approach first. If you dive deeper on the problem you're facing, please, share more parts of your code.